# Does counting inaccessibles have a fixpoint?

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

Assume the existence of a proper class of inaccessibles $I$, and let $f : \mathrm{Ord} \to I$ denote the unique strictly increasing class surjection given by Mostowski Collapse. Does $f$ have a fixpoint? More generally, is the existence of a proper class of inaccessibles needed, or is an inaccessible $\kappa$ such that $f : \kappa \to (\kappa \cap I)$ has the previously listed properties special on its own?

Comment: @Reveillark Right, I'll change the question accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

No it doesn't imply that. If we let $\kappa$ be the least fixed point of the increasing enumeration of inaccessibles, then $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC with a proper class of inaccessibles and no such fixed point. On the other hand, stronger large cardinal properties imply such fixed points exist... e.g. if there are any Mahlo cardinals then they have this property.

(And really it's a large cardinal property of its own, stronger in consistency strength than a proper class of inaccessibles, but much weaker than the existence of a Mahlo cardinal. Such a $\kappa$ is sometimes called $1$-inaccessible, in anticipation of a hierarchy where $2$-inaccessibles are fixed points in the enumeration of $1$-inaccessibles and so on, though the terminology concerning properties between inaccessible and Mahlo is not very standardized.)

Comment: By a proper class of inaccessibles, you certainly mean relative to $V_\kappa$, right? Could you elaborate on why these exist on that stage?

Comment: @univalence Think about $f^{-1}(\kappa\cap I)$ assuming that there are only boundedly many inaccessibles below $\kappa$. We get that $\kappa$ is the $\alpha$th inaccessible for some $\alpha<\kappa$.

Comment: @univalence Yes, relative to the model. "There is a proper class of inaccessbles" holding in a model means the model's inaccessibles are unbounded in the model's ordinals. (And in this nice full transitive model, everything is absolute, so it just means the actual inaccessibles are unbounded in $\kappa$. And I see Noah already elaborated on why that holds.)